# How to save the value of textformfield?

Tags: flutter

I have multiple TextFormFields that contains data pulled from Realtime Database and it gets displayed in an Edit Information page.

```
    final nameController = TextEditingController();
    final descriptionController = TextEditingController();

    setState(() {
      nameController.text = widget.name;
      descriptionController.text = widget.description;
    });
```

```
TextFormField(
   controller: nameController,
   autofocus: false,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
   labelText: 'Name',
   border: OutlineInputBorder(),),
),
```

Above codes will show name and description already in Edit Information page. However, when I type a new value for name and click on a different TextFormField, the name TextFormField goes back to its original value because of the controller. How can I save the state of the new TextFormField, if there is any, and update with the new value? Should I use onSaved or onChanged?

Information will be updated after clicking on this button:

```
ElevatedButton(
   onPressed: () {
   updateData(nameController.text,
   descriptionController.text, widget.passkey);
   Navigator.of(context).pop();},
   child: Text('Update')),
```

Update function:

```
  void updateData(String name, String description, var id) {
    Map<String, String> newvalue = {'name': name, 'description': description};
    databaseref.child(id).update(newvalue);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to setstate. Just remove Setstate from

```
setState(() {
      nameController.text = widget.name;
      descriptionController.text = widget.description;
    });
```

And Define your controller like

```
final controller = TextEditingController(text: "Your initial value");
```

Comment: I get a ```Failed assertion: line 200 pos 15: 'initialValue == null || controller == null': is not true.``` error.

Comment: please check you are getting data in widget.name?

Comment: Yes, I am! I put widget.name in labeltext too and it is working.

Comment: ohh Sorry! I think you can use controller or initialvalue one at a time. try to remove controller. let me know it is working or not

Comment: Define Controller like this and remove initial value
final controller = TextEditingController(text: "Your initial value");

Answer (score -1):

#### Instead of calling setState and assigning values to the controller, you can give these values to the *initialValue* attribute of the TextFormField and then update the controllers with the *Onchanged* method of TextformField.

JUST LIKE SO:

```
// controllers
 final nameController = TextEditingController();
 final descriptionController = TextEditingController();

// Adding initial value and updating it when the user edit the form
TextFormField(
   controller: nameController,
   initialValue: widget.name
   onChanged: (newValue) => nameController.text.value = newValue,
   autofocus: false,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
   labelText: 'Name',
   border: OutlineInputBorder(),),
),
```

Comment: I get a ```Failed assertion: line 200 pos 15: 'initialValue == null || controller == null': is not true.``` error.